# Activity View Controller not showing the entire popup

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

I am trying to make a drawing app and I want to add the activity view controller. It works on the iPhone, but it will not show the entire view controller on the iPad. I have tried many different approaches based off what I have read, but the result is the same. Any help is appreciate.

[image: Ipad error]

Code:
@IBAction func actionsTapped(_ sender: Any) {

```
    // Setting description
    let message = "Actions for your drawing"
    
    // Get the image to save
    let image = getImage()

    let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [message, image], applicationActivities: nil)
    
    // Ipad popup
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = (self.view)
    
    // Remove Ipad arrow
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.down
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 0, height: 0)
    
    // Pre-configuring activity items
    activityViewController.activityItemsConfiguration = [
        UIActivity.ActivityType.message,
        UIActivity.ActivityType.print,
        UIActivity.ActivityType.saveToCameraRoll,
        UIActivity.ActivityType.airDrop
    ] as? UIActivityItemsConfigurationReading
    
    // Exclude
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [
        UIActivity.ActivityType.postToWeibo,
        UIActivity.ActivityType.addToReadingList,
        UIActivity.ActivityType.postToFlickr,
        UIActivity.ActivityType.postToVimeo,
        UIActivity.ActivityType.postToTencentWeibo,
        UIActivity.ActivityType.postToFacebook
    ]
    
    activityViewController.isModalInPresentation = true
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

As someone pointed out, which I tried changing the height and width in the sourceRect does not work. See below where I changed

```
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 0, height: 0)
```

to

```
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 500, height: 500)
```

[image: heigh x and width]

My initial thought was that x and y would change the position of the popup and height and width change the size, but it seems that it's the reverse in sourceRect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're misunderstanding what the `sourceRect` is. It has nothing to do, in and of itself, with the size of the activity view controller. It determines *where the arrow points to.*

The activity view controller always has its own full size. I suspect that what's going wrong here is due to this line:

```
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.down
```

That forces the whole activity view controller to appear *above* the source rect (i.e. more toward the top of the screen) — but there isn't room. If you just cut that line, the activity view controller may be able to appear where there *is* room.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you for everything!

Comment: And I learned something too: as you can tell from my comments on your deleted answer, I had no idea that giving a bad arrow direction could cause the view controller interface to be truncated! So this Q and A really might be useful to others.